# What kinds of multiple integrals are "allowed"? e.g. $\int_0^a \int_0^a f(a)\,da\,da$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This is something I was thinking about when I was making an effort to catalog all the different types of multiple integrals. According to my current understanding, it seems like some are allowed while others aren't. For example, two variables with constant limits is always allowed.

$$
\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 f(a)\,da\,db
\tag{1}
$$

Consider two variables with one constant and one variable limit. If the constant limit is on the outside, it is allowed.

$$
\int_0^\pi \int_0^b f(a)\,da\,db
\tag{2}
$$

From what I understand, if the variable in the variable limit is to be $a$ or $b$, it can't be on the outside. For example, the following would be allowed, but confusing, since the $a$ on the outside is not really the same variable as the $a$ on the inside:

$$
\int_0^a \int_0^1 f(a)\,da\,db
\tag{3}
$$

And moving on to two variable limits, the following would be allowed (but confusing, since the $a$ on the outside has nothing to do with the $a$ on the inside).

$$
\int_0^a \int_0^b f(a)\,da\,db
\tag{4}
$$

While the following would be disallowed because it is nonsensical.

$$
\int_0^a \int_0^b f(a)\,db\,da
\tag{5}
$$

And what about integrating over the same variable twice?

$$
\int_0^\pi \int_0^1 f(a)\,da\,da
\tag{6}
$$

$(6)$ seems to fall into "allowed-but-confusing", since the inner integral gets evaluated, becomes a constant, and then the only effect of evaluating the outer integral (or any subsequent layers of integrals) is to multiply it by $\pi$.

But what about something like this?

$$
\int_0^a \int_0^a f(a)\,da\,da
\tag{7}
$$

I'd like to know if my judgements are correct, how to think about this, and if there's any cases I forgot -- I'm particularly curious about numbers $(5)$ and $(7)$.

Comment: $(7)$ simplifies to $a\right(F(a) - F(0)\left)$, where $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$. It's not, uh, incorrect, I'm just not sure that it represents anything intuitive about the function. The volume of a prism with height $a$ and face given by the region bound by $f$, $x=0$, $x=a$ and the $y$-axis?

Comment: $(7)$ is ambiguous. It could be $=\int_0^a (F_1(a)-F_1(0))\,da=-aF_1(0)+F_2(a)-F_2(0)$ where $F_i$ is ith antiderivative of $f$ or it could be $=a(F_1(a)-F_1(0))$.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're falling into a trap many new students to of *notation first, meaning second*. You are writing things down and *then* asking what they mean. This is akin to writing a bunch of words and then asking "what does this sentence mean?".

I'm not going to go through each of your 7 integrals to say which does or does not make sense, nor will I give you a general "rule", because that really isn't the point here. Some of the integrals you write are ambiguous at best and nonsensical at worst, such as 7.

This question shouldn't come up if you think about meaning  and **then** think about how to convey meaning *through* notation. For example in 7, if you want to integrate $f$ over some square, there are much better ways to write it. If you mean something else, then write it in a better way.

Writing down notation then trying to figure out if it's "allowed" is not good math.

I ask you a question. Which of the following English sentences are "allowed"?

I know "The cat chases the mouse" is okay, but is "chases mouse cat The" okay? How about "Cat cat chases mouse the" or "Cat cat cat cat cat"? Would the last one be nonsensical, or just ambiguous?

This is EXACTLY what you are asking. You are reusing and permuting symbols to see if there is meaning.

Comment: I too know this is a pattern many new students fall into. It's so easy to learn/be taught math as a series of arbitrary rules to be followed. Heartbreaking! I hate to see people I am teaching do this. Math is based on meaning, not arbitrary rules -- I agree. However, I'd ask you not to assume things of me -- I'm not a new student. I happen to think your question about English sentences is perfectly valid and interesting (with the caveat that English is not a formal system). Perhaps a better word for "allowed" would be "grammatically valid". My question is about grammar.

Comment: Just a further thought -- my viewpoint is probably influenced by my training in computer science. For me, it's natural to look at a formal language and ask what strings are contained in it and which are not. Doing the same thing with integrals helps me imagine how an imaginary machine would compute my answer as a series of trivial steps. (Not saying you have to use this intuition as well; that's just what helps me!)